# MySQL Unknown column in where clause for simple select statement

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, collation

I have a very basic select statement that is causing a column unknown error. The problem with the query happens when I try to use a character instead of just numbers in the variable. Wondering if it has anything to do with Collation.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$titleno=$_REQUEST['title_no'];
$titleno=mysql_real_escape_string($titleno);
$titleno = utf8_decode($titleno); //tried without this before but didn't work
$query="SELECT * FROM `Titles` WHERE `title-no` = '".$titleno."'"; 
//tried various versions of this query - left it as single quotes as that seems to be the correct way. This only fails when a character is entered. Numbers work fine.  

echo "query - <br> $query <br>";    
$get_title_result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
//here I get the unknown column name error - MySQL treats the titleno as the column name
```

Echo output:

```
SELECT * FROM `Titles` WHERE `title-no` = '1234566d' 
Unknown column '1234566d' in 'where clause'
```

If I didn't use the 'd' in title-no, it works fine....Also, I tried a different column name that doesn't have the hyphen and still get the same behavior. The DB defines collation for title-no as latin1_swedish_ci. (This problem doesn't occur when I paste the query into mysqladmin)

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `Titles` (  
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
 `title-no` varchar(15) NOT NULL,  
  UNIQUE KEY `title-no` (`title-no`),  
  KEY `id` (`id`)  
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  
  AUTO_INCREMENT=9090949 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9090949 ;
```

**RESOLVED:** The issue was not with this query. It was with a subsequent query. I was confused because I was only echoing this query. My bad. Thank you all for your support! :)

Comment: can you also paste your table definition?

Comment: Keep the backticks around the field names. But never use backticks around values, otherwise mysql will interpret them as field names and throw an error.

Comment: Where in your code do you echo your query? Can you update your question with the echo statement added to your code?

Comment: @Jocelyn - Added the echo statement. It's right before running the query...

Comment: I suggest re-checking once more your quotes and backticks. I don't see what else might cause your error...quotes go around text values, and backticks go around field names.

Comment: The query looks fine. Maybe this is a silly tip, but make sure **this** query is the one throwing the error, and it's not a different query further down the script where you forgot the proper single quotes :) Only then would I start digging into weird character encoding issues...

Comment: @J. Miller thanks. That was the problem - it was a different query that was throwing the error. Since I printed only this specific query I wrongfully assumed this one the one with the error. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Titles WHERE `Titles`.`title-no` = '" . $titleno . "'";
```

Comment: Solved. I forgot the apostrophe, because of `-` of table, too.

Comment: @Gabriel I tried your suggestion (after fixing the quotes) and it didn't work. You need to put ticks or quotes for the title-no because of the hyphen (i think, otherwise it treats it as title only which is wrong) Thanks.

Comment: @Jocelyn - I've tried all kinds of quotes, single quotes, ticks, etc. The query works fine with numbers, i'm thinking it's something to do with adding the character in there...not sure what's going. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick conversion to statement-based query (which is using MySQLi, adapt as necessary, your code or this example). The assumption is that the underlying prepared statement engine *knows* that you cannot specify a column name with placeholders in a prepared statement, so it should be passing it correctly (here's hoping :-)

```
$titleno=$_REQUEST['title_no'];
$statement=mysqli_prepare($your_mysqli_link, "SELECT `id` FROM `Titles` WHERE `title-no` = ?"); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 's', $titleno);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $found_id);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement);
echo "found id: $found_id";
```